# How do I build utilities with my Go web app on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, go, godeps

I've developed a web app using Go, which I've deployed to Heroku. I'm using [mattes/migrate](https://github.com/mattes/migrate) to manage migrations. It works great locally, but the `migrate` command-line binary isn't available when I deploy to Heroku.

The only binaries that are included are my own. Is there a way to have Godeps compile and install binaries provided by a dependency?

Comment: I've come across an issue in the Godep repo which exactly describes the issue I'm having as well. 
https://github.com/tools/godep/issues/306

Comment: You could also run `migrate` against your Heroku Postgres DB remotely from your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file where you include the executable path.

See [this issue for Goose](https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose/) (mattes/migrate competitor)

I'd expect the equivalent for mattes/migrate would be:

```
package main

import _ "github.com/mattes/migrate"
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's current recommended solution is to simply clone the command into your own repo (see github.com/tools/godep/issues/306).

I copied the `mattes/migrate/main.go` into the `cmd/migrate` directory in my own project. This builds the command just like my own server command.

It's not ideal, but it works.